# CartPoleV0 model is not getting trained in even after 1500+ episodes using deep Q-learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, deep-rl, dqn, gym

I am new to deep Q learning and trying to train the open AI cartpole_V0 game using deep Q learning. Here is my code:

```
import gym
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 
import tensorflow as tf
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


EPISODES = 5000
output_dir = "/home/ug2018/mst/18114017/ML/"
EPSILON = 1
REPLAY_MEMORY = deque(maxlen=800)
MIN_EPSILON = 0.01
DECAY_RATE = 0.995
MINIBATCH = 750
GAMMA = 0.99

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
action_size = env.action_space.n


class DQNagent:

    def __init__(self):

        self.fit_model = self.create_model()

        self.predict_model = self.create_model()
        self.predict_model.set_weights(self.fit_model.get_weights())

        self.targets = []
        self.states = []

    def create_model(self):

        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation ="relu",input_dim = state_size))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation ="relu"))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation ="relu"))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation ="relu"))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation ="relu"))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation ="relu"))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(action_size, activation="linear"))
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model

    def model_summary(self,model):
        return model.summary()

    def get_q(self, state):
        return self.predict_model.predict(state)

    def train(self,batch_size): 
        minibatch = random.sample(REPLAY_MEMORY, batch_size)
        for state, reward, action, new_state, done in minibatch:
            if done :
                target = reward
            else:
                target = reward + (GAMMA * np.amax(self.get_q(new_state)[0]))
            target_f = self.get_q(state) 
            target_f[0][action] = target

            self.states.append(state[0])
            self.targets.append(target_f[0])

        self.fit_weights(self.states,self.targets)
    
  
    def fit_weights(self, states, targets):
        self.fit_model.fit(np.array(states), np.array(targets), batch_size = MINIBATCH, epochs = 1 ,verbose=0)
    
    def predict_save(self, name): 
        self.predict_model.save_weights(name)
    def fit_save(self, name):    
        self.fit_model.save_weights(name)

    



agent = DQNagent()
print(agent.fit_model.summary())




x=[]
y=[]
z=[]

def update_graph(z,y):
    plt.xlabel("Episodes")
    plt.ylabel("Score")
    plt.plot(z,y)
    plt.pause(0.5)
plt.show()
    

for eps in range(EPISODES):
    env.reset()
    done = False
    state = env.reset()
    state = np.reshape(state, [1,state_size])
    time = 0
    exp=0
    elp=0
    while not done:
       
        if EPSILON >= np.random.rand():
            exp +=1
            action = random.randrange(action_size) 
        else:
            elp +=1
            action = np.argmax(agent.get_q(state)[0])
        new_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        new_state = np.reshape(new_state,[1, state_size])
        if not done:
            reward = -10
        else:
            reward = 10
        REPLAY_MEMORY.append((state,reward,action,new_state,done))
        state = new_state
        time += 1
    x.append([eps,exp,elp,time,EPSILON])
    y.append(time)
    z.append(eps)
    update_graph(z,y)
    if (len(REPLAY_MEMORY)) >= MINIBATCH:
        agent.train(MINIBATCH)
        if EPSILON > MIN_EPSILON:
            EPSILON *= DECAY_RATE
    if eps % 50 == 0:
        agent.predict_save(output_dir + "predict_weights_" + '{:04d}'.format(eps) + ".hdf5")
        agent.fit_save(output_dir + "fit_weights_" + '{:04d}'.format(eps) + ".hdf5")
    with open("score_vs_eps.txt", "w") as output:
        output.write("Episodes"+"   "+"Exploration"+"   " + "Exploitation" + "  "+ "Score" + "  " + "Epsilon"+"\n")
        for eps,exp,elp,time,epsilon in x:
            output.write("      "+str(eps)+"        "+str(exp)+"        "+str(elp)+"        "+str(time)+"       "+"{:.4f}".format(epsilon) +"\n")

agent.predict_model.save('CartPole_predict_model')
agent.predict_model.save('CartPole_fit_model')
```

Code is running perfectly but the model is taking too many episodes to get trained and even after it scores 200, there is no continuity of it. Could please help me with how can I train the model in fewer episodes and maintain the continuity of the 200 scores?

Here are some of the steps listed:

```
Episodes Exploration Exploitation Score    Epsilon
  0        18        0        18       1.0000
  1        32        0        32       1.0000
  2        43        0        43       1.0000
  3        17        0        17       1.0000
  4        17        0        17       1.0000
  5        16        0        16       1.0000
  6        13        0        13       1.0000
  7        21        0        21       1.0000
  8        16        0        16       1.0000
  9        20        0        20       1.0000
  10        35       0        35       1.0000
  11        14       0        14       1.0000
  12        13       0        13       1.0000
  13        12       0        12       1.0000
  14        16       0        16       1.0000
  15        17       0        17       1.0000
  16        27       0        27       1.0000
  17        24       0        24       1.0000
  18        14       0        14       1.0000
  19        28       0        28       1.0000
  20        20       0        20       1.0000
  21        13       0        13       1.0000
  22        12       0        12       1.0000
  23        23       0        23       1.0000
  24        17       0        17       1.0000
  25        43       0        43       1.0000
  26        61       0        61       1.0000
  27        29       0        29       1.0000
  28        21       0        21       1.0000
  29        17       0        17       1.0000
  30        41       0        41       1.0000
  31        9        0        9        1.0000
  32        18       0        18       1.0000
  33        23       0        23       1.0000
  34        28       0        28       0.9950
  35        24       0        24       0.9900
  36        25       0        25       0.9851
  37        28       1        29       0.9801
  38        26       1        27       0.9752
  39        35       2        37       0.9704
  40        19       0        19       0.9655
  41        48       0        48       0.9607
  42        25       2        27       0.9559
  43        13       0        13       0.9511
  44        20       2        22       0.9464
  45        21       0        21       0.9416
  46        13       0        13       0.9369
  47        28       5        33       0.9322
  48        23       3        26       0.9276
  49        24       1        25       0.9229
  50        20       2        22       0.9183
  51        13       0        13       0.9137
  52        19       1        20       0.9092
  53        13       1        14       0.9046
  54        18       1        19       0.9001
  55        12       1        13       0.8956
  56        29       7        36       0.8911
  57        28       2        30       0.8867
  58        16       1        17       0.8822
  59        28       6        34       0.8778
  60        13       3        16       0.8734
  61        15       4        19       0.8691
  62        19       2        21       0.8647
  63        27       4        31       0.8604
  64        19       4        23       0.8561
  65        16       1        17       0.8518
  66        60       9        69       0.8475
  67        24       1        25       0.8433
  68        21       7        28       0.8391
  69        14       0        14       0.8349
  70        31       4        35       0.8307
  71        64       13       77       0.8266
  72        58       13       71       0.8224
  73        32       9        41       0.8183
  74        15       1        16       0.8142
  75        23       6        29       0.8102
  76        27       5        32       0.8061
  77        66       6        82       0.8021
  78        30       6        36       0.7981
  79        74       22       96       0.7941
  80        14       1        15       0.7901
  81        18       1        19       0.7862
  82        28       7        35       0.7822
  83        28       4        32       0.7783
  84        12       2        14       0.7744
  85        10       2        12       0.7705
  86        21       4        25       0.7667
  87        13       6        19       0.7629
  88        19       6        25       0.7590
  89        16       4        20       0.7553
  90        46       16       62       0.7515
  91        12       1        13       0.7477
  92        30       15       45       0.7440
  93        38       9        47       0.7403
  94        14       7        21       0.7366
  95        10       1        11       0.7329
  96        16       8        24       0.7292
  97        10       2        12       0.7256
  98        20       5        25       0.7219
  99        19       7        26       0.7183
  100       31       9        40       0.7147
  .
  .
  . 
  1522        0        104       104      0.0100
  1523        0        35        35       0.0100
  1524        0        27        27       0.0100
  1525        0        52        52       0.0100
  1526        0        25        25       0.0100
  1527        1        199       200      0.0100
  1528        0        30        30       0.0100
  1529        0        57        57       0.0100
  1530        0        35        35       0.0100
  1531        0        25        25       0.0100
  1532        0        22        22       0.0100
  1533        0        24        24       0.0100
  1534        1        199       200      0.0100
  1535        0        68        68       0.0100
  1536        0        200       200      0.0100
  1537        0        22        22       0.0100
  1538        2        42        44       0.0100
  1539        1        111       112      0.0100
  1540        0        91        91       0.0100
  1541        0        45        45       0.0100
  1542        2        108       110      0.0100
  1543        1        181       182      0.0100
  1544        0        30        30       0.0100
  1545        0        21        21       0.0100
  1546        1        25        26       0.0100
  1547        4        196       200      0.0100
  1548        0        95        95       0.0100
  1549        0        53        53       0.0100
  1550        0        55        55       0.0100
  1551        0        29        29       0.0100
  1552        0        40        40       0.0100
  1553        0        25        25       0.0100
  1554        0        33        33       0.0100
  1555        0        63        63       0.0100
  1556        0        23        23       0.0100
  1557        0        45        45       0.0100
  1558        0        25        25       0.0100
  1559        0        36        36       0.0100
  1560        0        24        24       0.0100
  1561        1        31        32       0.0100
  1562        0        30        30       0.0100
  1563        1        56        57       0.0100
  1564        0        22        22       0.0100
  1565        0        20        20       0.0100
  1566        1        22        23       0.0100
  1567        0        45        45       0.0100
  1568        1        50        51       0.0100
  1569        0        25        25       0.0100
  1570        0        30        30       0.0100
  1571        2        198       200      0.0100
  1572        2        198       200      0.0100
  1573        1        185       186      0.0100
  1574        0        26        26       0.0100
  1575        4        196       200      0.0100
  1576        3        197       200      0.0100
  1577        1        29        30       0.0100
  1578        0        25        25       0.0100
  1579        0        32        32       0.0100
  1580        3        197       200      0.0100
  1581        1        23        24       0.0100
  1582        0        25        25       0.0100
  1583        0        66        66       0.0100
  1584        1        27        28       0.0100
  1585        0        32        32       0.0100
  1586        0        21        21       0.0100
  1587        0        23        23       0.0100
  1588        1        47        48       0.0100
  1589        0        42        42       0.0100
  1590        0        26        26       0.0100
  1591        0        47        47       0.0100
  1592        0        200       200      0.0100
  1593        2        52        54       0.0100
  1594        1        19        20       0.0100
  1595        0        33        33       0.0100
  1596        0        27        27       0.0100 
  1597        1        79        80       0.0100
  1598        0        54        54       0.0100
  1599        0        50        50       0.0100
  1600        0        25        25       0.0100
```

I have initiated the epsilon with 1 and it has already reached its minimum possible value. Still, the result is very fluctuating from the score's point of view. Why is this happening? How can I maintain the continuity?

Comment: Please help me with this, how can I train this model to score 200 scores continuously. Am I doing anything wrong in applying the concept?

Comment: You make the reward 10 for it being done and -10 for it staying alive. Reversing those should help. Right now, it’s being trained to fall as quickly as possible. Another problem is that your neural network is way larger than it needs to be for this simple environment.

Comment: @S2673 , Thank you for pointing out the error. Could you please tell me how to decide how many layers will be good for optimal performance?

Comment: You can make a guess based on how complex the environment is and your experience with similar environments, but there is no one way I know of to easily decide the number of layers. From my experience with CartPole, you need very few layers or none at all. Around 2 should probably work for you.

Comment: @S2673 , As I understand the value stored in the done variable is false until the episode gets terminated. From that point of view, I have written the code rightly. It would have not been reached the score of 200 if I had implemented it wrongly.

Comment: Right, if `done` is false when the episode is still going then `if not done` will return `True` and the reward will be -10, meaning it is bad for the cart to balance the pole longer. I’m not sure why you got the 200 rewards, but it could be random. If you think the code is right, then you might want to try changing the parameters like learning rate and hidden layer sizes.